# PHP Turnover Thousands to Million

Tags: php

Whould like to make 10000 thousands to become 10 million in PHP.
Well actually I only need to remove 3 zeros from the end I guess...

Please help trying to figure it out!

```
  $turnover=10000;
```

...?

Comment: maths might be a good start

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change it to 10 million, you will need to multiply

```
$turnover=10000*1000;
```

If you want to get 10000 you will need to divide.

```
$turnover=10000/1000;
```

Try reading some basic PHP documentation. There is a lot of good online tutorials to find.

Comment: *10000*100* is only 1 mio. not 10!